# Navbar expands on wrong side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am having issues with my Bootstrap Navbar. It seems working fine for a couple months ago but now it just does weird things, no idea why. My biggest problem is when on small window sizes I try to expand my Navmenu it does it on the right side instead of underneath the actual hamburger.

This is my nav code:

```
<div class="menue">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Kosmetik Asura</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#ueber">Über</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#angebote">Angebot</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#news">News</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to change?

Thanks in advance!

PS: this is on

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

[image: example]

CSS:

```
/*NAV*/
nav li{
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  font-size: 1em;
}

nav li:hover{
  border-left: 2px solid black;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #000;
}

.navbar{
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 90px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid grey;
  border-top: 1px solid grey;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}


.nav-link{
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: do you mean the list seem in right side instead under `Kosmetik Asura` ??

Comment: Right now its under 'Kosmetik Asura' but I want it underneath the hamburger on the right. It also looks kinda weird and not how I think it should.

Comment: see my answer please

Comment: so add your css also

Comment: Why are you using 4.0 beta 2? 4.1 has been released.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`align` `ul` to `right`

```css
.navbar-nav{
    float: right!important;

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <div class="menue">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Kosmetik Asura</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
          <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#ueber">Über</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#angebote">Angebot</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#news">News</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#kontakt">Kontakt</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </div>
```

**TO YOUR COMMENT:**

> I get a black bar on the left of the expanded menu and its somehow
>   transparent.

remove it from your css:

```
 border-left: 2px solid black; 


box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 5px #000;
```

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: Its on the right side now but still looks ugly... not how bootstrap normally looks. Am I missing something?
Not only I get a black bar on the left of the expanded menu and its somehow transparent.

Comment: the normally bootstrap is that list open in left side

Comment: delete the border that you set in your css `nav li {
   border-left: 2px solid black;}`

Comment: Okay I see my problem now... In the past, the Navbar changed its hight with the expanded list. Now the navbar stays the same hight and the navbar just expands over the page which makes it look weird in my case.

Anyone knows how to change that?

Comment: just remove your `.navbar` style beacause bootstrap style it alone

Comment: i mean the `height` and `shadow`

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Now is there a way how I can avoid that the navbar looks different while expanding than when completly expanded? Concerning padding/margin..

Comment: Is there also a responsive porppertiy for `.col-md-7`?